# SQLite database wont initialize from PHP initilization

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

Here is the SQL in question

```
--plants table--

CREATE TABLE plants (
  plant_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
  plant_name TEXT NOT NULL,
  genus TEXT NOT NULL,
);


INSERT INTO
  plants (plant_id, plant_name, genus)
VALUES
  (1, 'Pink Muhly Grass', 'Muhlenbergia capillaris');
INSERT INTO
  plants (plant_id, plant_name, genus)
VALUES
  (2, 'Feather reed grass', 'Calamagrostis x acutiflora');
INSERT INTO
  plants (plant_id, plant_name, genus)
VALUES
  (3, 'Smooth Shadbush', 'Amelanchier laevis');
INSERT INTO
  plants (plant_id, plant_name, genus)
VALUES
  (4, 'Chestnut Oak', 'Quercus montana');
INSERT INTO
  plants (plant_id, plant_name, genus)
VALUES
  (5, 'Sideoats Grama', 'Bouteloua curipendula');
INSERT INTO
  plants (plant_id, plant_name, genus)
VALUES
  (6, 'Feverfew', 'Tanasetum parthenium');
INSERT INTO
  plants (plant_id, plant_name, genus)
VALUES
  (7, 'Prairie Cord Grass', 'Spartina pectinata');
INSERT INTO
  plants (plant_id, plant_name, genus)
VALUES
  (8, 'Christmas Fern', 'Polystichum acrostichoides');
INSERT INTO
  plants (plant_id, plant_name, genus)
VALUES
  (9, 'Climbing Hydrangea', 'Hydrangea anomala');
INSERT INTO
  plants (plant_id, plant_name, genus)
VALUES
  (10, 'New England Aster', 'Aster novae angliae');
INSERT INTO
  plants (plant_id, plant_name, genus)
VALUES
  (11, 'Nannyberry', 'Viburnum lentago');
INSERT INTO
  plants (plant_id, plant_name, genus)
VALUES
  (12, 'Hyssop', 'Hyssopus officinalis');

CREATE TABLE plant-tags (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
  plant_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  tag_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (plant_id) REFERENCES plants(plant_id)
  FOREIGN KEY (tag_id) REFERENCES tags(tag_id)

);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
   VALUES (1,1,4);

 INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
   VALUES (2,1,5);

   INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
   VALUES (3,1,6);

   INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
   VALUES (4,1,7);

 INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
   VALUES (5,1,8);

   INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
   VALUES (6,1,12);

   INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
   VALUES (7,1,13);

 INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
   VALUES (8,1,14);

   INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
   VALUES (9,1,18);


INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (10, 2, 4);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (11, 2, 5);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (12, 2, 6);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (13, 2, 7);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (14, 2, 8);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (15, 2, 9);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (16, 2, 10);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (17, 2, 11);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (18, 2, 12);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (19, 2, 13);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (20, 2, 14);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (21, 2, 18);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (22, 2, 3);



INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (23, 3, 1);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (24, 3, 2);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (25, 3, 4);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (26, 3, 5);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (27, 3, 7);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (28, 3, 8);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (29, 3, 9);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (30, 3, 12);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (31, 3, 13);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (32, 3, 14);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (33, 3, 15);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (34, 3, 17);




INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (35, 4, 1);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (36, 4, 3);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (37, 4, 5);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (38, 4, 6);


INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (39, 4, 7);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (40, 4, 8);


INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (41, 4, 12);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (42, 4, 13);


INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (43, 4, 14);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (44, 4, 20);




INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (45, 5, 3);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (46, 5, 4);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (47, 5, 5);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (48, 5, 6);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (49, 5, 7);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (50, 5, 8);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (51, 5, 9);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (52, 5, 10);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (53, 5, 12);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (54, 5, 13);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (55, 5, 14);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (56, 5, 18);


INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (57, 6, 1);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (58, 6, 2);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (59, 6, 5);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (60, 6, 6);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (61, 6, 7);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (62, 6, 8);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (63, 6, 9);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (64, 6, 12);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (65, 6, 13);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (66, 6, 14);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (67, 6, 22);




INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (68, 7, 3);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES (69, 7, 4);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(70, 7, 6);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(71, 7, 7);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(72, 7, 8);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(73, 7, 10);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(74, 7, 12);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(75, 7, 14);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(76, 7, 15);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(77, 7, 18);


INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(78, 8, 4);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(79, 8, 5);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(80, 8, 7);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(81, 8, 9);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(82, 8, 12);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(83, 8, 13);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(84, 8, 15);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(85, 8, 16);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(86, 8, 23);



INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(87, 9, 2);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(88, 9, 5);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(89, 9, 7);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(90, 9, 8);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(91, 9, 10);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(92, 9, 12);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(93, 9, 13);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(94, 9, 15);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(95, 9, 16);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(96, 9, 19);


INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(97, 10, 1);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(98, 10, 4);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(99, 10, 6);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(100, 10, 9);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(101, 10, 12);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(102, 10, 13);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(103, 10, 14);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(104, 10, 15);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(105, 10, 21);


INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(106, 11, 1);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(107, 11, 2);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(108, 11, 5);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(109, 11, 7);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(110, 11, 8);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(111, 11, 12);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(112, 11, 13);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(113, 11, 14);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(114, 11, 15);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(115, 11, 17);



INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(116, 12, 21);

INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(117, 12, 1);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(118, 12, 2);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(119, 12, 4);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(120, 12, 7);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(121, 12, 8);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(122, 12, 9);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(123, 12, 12);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(124, 12, 14);
INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES(125, 12, 16);

CREATE TABLE tags (
  tag_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
  tag_name TEXT NOT NULL,
);

INSERT INTO
tags(id, tag_name)
VALUES (1, "edible");

INSERT INTO
tags(id, tag_name)
VALUES (2, "scent");

INSERT INTO
tags(id, tag_name)
VALUES (3, "sound");

INSERT INTO
tags(id, tag_name)
VALUES (4, "tactile");

INSERT INTO
tags(id,tag_name)
VALUES (5, "visual");

INSERT INTO
tags(id,tag_name)
VALUES (6, "exploratory constructive");

INSERT INTO
tags(id, tag_name)
VALUES (7, "exploratory sensory");

INSERT INTO
tags(id, tag_name)
VALUES (8, "physical");

INSERT INTO
tags(id, tag_name)
VALUES (9, "imaginative");

INSERT INTO
tags(id, tag_name)
VALUES (10, "restorative");

INSERT INTO
tags(id, tag_name)
VALUES (11, "rules-based");

INSERT INTO
tags(id, tag_name)
VALUES (12, "bio-based");

INSERT INTO
tags(id, tag_name)
VALUES (13, "perennial");

INSERT INTO
tags(id, tag_name)
VALUES (14, "full sun");

INSERT INTO
tags(id, tag_name)
VALUES (5, "partial shade");

INSERT INTO
tags(id, tag_name)
VALUES (16, "full shade");

INSERT INTO
tags(id, tag_name)
VALUES (17, "shrub");

INSERT INTO
tags(id, tag_name)
VALUES (18, "grass");

INSERT INTO
tags(id, tag_name)
VALUES (19, "vine");

INSERT INTO
tags(id, tag_name)
VALUES (20, "tree");

INSERT INTO
tags(id, tag_name)
VALUES (21, "flower");

INSERT INTO
tags(id, tag_name)
VALUES (22, "groundcover");

INSERT INTO
tags(id, tag_name)
VALUES (23, "fern");
```

and the initialization. This code doesn't contain errors, but I'm including it for posterity. I am new to using SQL and don't know how to troubleshoot. the error thrown is "Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near ")": syntax error in line 66" (of the initialization file). That is the line where the database connection is instantiated.

```
 <?php
// Open a connection to an SQLite database stored in filename: $db_filename.
// Returns: Connection to database.
function open_sqlite_db($db_filename)
{
  if (!file_exists($db_filename)) {
    throw new Exception('Failed to open database. No such file: ' . $db_filename);
  }

  // database was already initialized. Just open it!
  $db_connection = new PDO('sqlite:' . $db_filename);
  $db_connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  return $db_connection;
}

// Open a connection to an SQLite database stored in filename: $db_filename.
// If database does not exists, will execute .sql file from $init_sql_filename
// to create and initialize the database. No database is created if there is
// an error the initialization SQL.
// Returns: Connection to database.
// Example: $db = init_sqlite_db('db/site.sqlite', 'db/init.sql');
function init_sqlite_db($db_filename, $init_sql_filename)
{
  // If the init SQL script does not exist, quit!
  if (!file_exists($init_sql_filename)) {
    throw new Exception("No such file: " . $init_sql_filename);
  }

  // create checksum of initialization script.
  $init_sql = file_get_contents($init_sql_filename);
  $init_checksum = md5($init_sql);

  // checksum used to create the database
  $init_checksum_filename = $init_sql_filename . ".checksum";

  // If the database doesn't exist, then the existing checksum is invalid. Delete it.
  if (!file_exists($db_filename) && file_exists($init_checksum_filename)) {
    unlink($init_checksum_filename);
  }

  // If the database exists, but no checksum file exists, then we have a consistency problem with the DB.
  if (file_exists($db_filename) && !file_exists($init_checksum_filename)) {
    throw new Exception("No checksum for existing database. Please regenerate your database (delete .sqlite file).");
  }

  // Get the existing checksum and compare it the init checksum.
  if (file_exists($init_checksum_filename)) {
    $current_checksum = file_get_contents($init_checksum_filename);

    if ($init_checksum != $current_checksum) {
      throw new Exception("Database initialization script has changed. Please regenerate your database (delete " . $db_filename . ").");
    }
  }

  // If the database does not exist, create it!
  if (!file_exists($db_filename)) {
    error_log("  creating database " . $db_filename . " from " . $init_sql_filename);

    // Create new database
    $db = new PDO('sqlite:' . $db_filename);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    try {
      // initialize database using .sql script
      $db->beginTransaction();
      $result = $db->exec($init_sql);
      $db->commit();
      if ($result !== FALSE) {
        file_put_contents($init_checksum_filename, $init_checksum);
        return $db;
      }
    } catch (PDOException $exception) {
      // If we had an error, then the DB did not initialize properly,
      // so let's delete it!
      unlink($db_filename);

      error_log("  failed to initialize database " . $db_filename . ". check your initialization SQL: " . $init_sql_filename);
      throw $exception;
    }
  } else {
    error_log("  opening database " . $db_filename);

    // database was already initialized. Just open it!
    $db = new PDO('sqlite:' . $db_filename);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $db;
  }

  return NULL;
}

// Execute a query ($sql) against a database ($db).
// Returns query results if query was successful.
// Returns null if query was not successful.
function exec_sql_query($db, $sql, $params = array())
{
  error_log('  executing SQL: ' . $sql);

  $query = $db->prepare($sql);
  if ($query and $query->execute($params)) {
    return $query;
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL contains error(s). I input it directly into [SQLFiddle and it is displaying error](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=b55b88ca066e082ede475a857c720798).

When it comes to inserting multiple entries into a single table, you don't need to use multiple `INSERT` statements, you can separate the values with a comma. I tested the updated SQL in [SQLFiddle and it works as expected](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=19d17fc8e8bad0a9a02b3be10c5aa95c)

Here is the updated initialization file:

```
CREATE TABLE plants (
  plant_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
  plant_name TEXT NOT NULL,
  genus TEXT NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO
  plants (plant_id, plant_name, genus)
VALUES
  (1, 'Pink Muhly Grass', 'Muhlenbergia capillaris'),
  (2, 'Feather reed grass', 'Calamagrostis x acutiflora'),
  (3, 'Smooth Shadbush', 'Amelanchier laevis'),
  (4, 'Chestnut Oak', 'Quercus montana'),
  (5, 'Sideoats Grama', 'Bouteloua curipendula'),
  (6, 'Feverfew', 'Tanasetum parthenium'),
  (7, 'Prairie Cord Grass', 'Spartina pectinata'),
  (8, 'Christmas Fern', 'Polystichum acrostichoides'),
  (9, 'Climbing Hydrangea', 'Hydrangea anomala'),
  (10, 'New England Aster', 'Aster novae angliae'),
  (11, 'Nannyberry', 'Viburnum lentago'),
  (12, 'Hyssop', 'Hyssopus officinalis');
  
CREATE TABLE plant-tags (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
  plant_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  tag_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (plant_id) REFERENCES plants(plant_id)
  FOREIGN KEY (tag_id) REFERENCES tags(tag_id)
);
  
 INSERT INTO
    plant-tags(id, plant_id, tag_id)
VALUES 
    (1,1,4),
    (2,1,5), 
    (3,1,6), 
    (4,1,7),
    (5,1,8),
    (6,1,12), 
    (7,1,13),
    (8,1,14),
    (9,1,18),
    (10, 2, 4),    
    (11, 2, 5),    
    (12, 2, 6),    
    (13, 2, 7),    
    (14, 2, 8),    
    (15, 2, 9),    
    (16, 2, 10),    
    (17, 2, 11),    
    (18, 2, 12),    
    (19, 2, 13),    
    (20, 2, 14),    
    (21, 2, 18),    
    (22, 2, 3),
    (23, 3, 1),    
    (24, 3, 2),    
    (25, 3, 4),    
    (26, 3, 5),    
    (27, 3, 7),    
    (28, 3, 8),    
    (29, 3, 9),    
    (30, 3, 12),    
    (31, 3, 13),    
    (32, 3, 14),    
    (33, 3, 15),    
    (34, 3, 17),
    (35, 4, 1),    
    (36, 4, 3),    
    (37, 4, 5),    
    (38, 4, 6),
    (39, 4, 7),    
    (40, 4, 8), 
    (41, 4, 12),    
    (42, 4, 13), 
    (43, 4, 14),    
    (44, 4, 20),  
    (45, 5, 3),  
    (46, 5, 4),   
    (47, 5, 5),  
    (48, 5, 6),  
    (49, 5, 7),  
    (50, 5, 8),  
    (51, 5, 9),  
    (52, 5, 10), 
    (53, 5, 12),
    (54, 5, 13),
    (55, 5, 14),
    (56, 5, 18),
    (57, 6, 1),
    (58, 6, 2),
    (59, 6, 5),    
    (60, 6, 6),    
    (61, 6, 7),    
    (62, 6, 8),    
    (63, 6, 9),    
    (64, 6, 12),    
    (65, 6, 13),    
    (66, 6, 14),    
    (67, 6, 22),
    (68, 7, 3),    
    (69, 7, 4),    
    (70, 7, 6),    
    (71, 7, 7),    
    (72, 7, 8),    
    (73, 7, 10),    
    (74, 7, 12),    
    (75, 7, 14),    
    (76, 7, 15),    
    (77, 7, 18),
    (78, 8, 4),
    (79, 8, 5),
    (80, 8, 7),
    (81, 8, 9),
    (82, 8, 12),
    (83, 8, 13),
    (84, 8, 15),
    (85, 8, 16),
    (86, 8, 23),
    (87, 9, 2),
    (88, 9, 5),
    (89, 9, 7),
    (90, 9, 8),
    (91, 9, 10),
    (92, 9, 12),
    (93, 9, 13),
    (94, 9, 15),
    (95, 9, 16),
    (96, 9, 19),
    (97, 10, 1),
    (98, 10, 4),
    (99, 10, 6),
    (100, 10, 9),
    (101, 10, 12),
    (102, 10, 13),
    (103, 10, 14),
    (104, 10, 15),
    (105, 10, 21),
    (106, 11, 1),
    (107, 11, 2),
    (108, 11, 5),
    (109, 11, 7),
    (110, 11, 8),
    (111, 11, 12),
    (112, 11, 13),
    (113, 11, 14),
    (114, 11, 15),
    (115, 11, 17),
    (116, 12, 21),
    (117, 12, 1),
    (118, 12, 2),
    (119, 12, 4),
    (120, 12, 7),
    (121, 12, 8),
    (122, 12, 9),
    (123, 12, 12),
    (124, 12, 14),
    (125, 12, 16);
    
CREATE TABLE tags (
  tag_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
  tag_name TEXT NOT NULL,
);

INSERT INTO
    tags(id, tag_name)
VALUES
    (1, "edible"),
    (2, "scent"),
    (3, "sound"),
    (4, "tactile"),
    (5, "visual"),
    (6, "exploratory constructive"),
    (7, "exploratory sensory"),
    (8, "physical"),
    (9, "imaginative"),
    (10, "restorative"),
    (11, "rules-based"),
    (12, "bio-based"),
    (13, "perennial"),
    (14, "full sun"),
    (5, "partial shade"),
    (16, "full shade"),
    (17, "shrub"),
    (18, "grass"),
    (19, "vine"),
    (20, "tree"),
    (21, "flower"),
    (22, "groundcover"),
    (23, "fern");
```

Comment: I appreciate the help. SQLfiddle also identifies an errant parantheses but doesn't say where it is. How can I track down such errors?

Comment: The way I did it was added all the `CREATE TABLE` statements first and ran after each time, then added all the `INSERT` blocks until an error was found.

Comment: Interesting, The fiddle indeed doesn't return any errors but the VSCode debugger does. PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "-": syntax error again at line 66:

Comment: Indeed, I would recommend only naming tables with underscores instead of hyphens.

Comment: Aha! that is helpful to remember

Comment: Good luck with it! If you found the answer helpful please remember to mark it acepted and/or upvote :)

Comment: I did but I'm too new for it to matter apparently :(